# Does write() system call block when the target page is on disk but not in page cache?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

[This question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-major-difference-between-the-buffer-cache-and-the-page-cache-Why-were-they-separate-entities-in-older-kernels-Why-were-they-merged-later-on) on Quora indicates to me that when write()ing to (part of) a file, the write buffer points to the page in the page cache where that portion of the file's memory is cached.  Thus, a write() system call "buffers" IO by immediately writing to the corresponding cached page in RAM, and marking the page as dirty.  Is this correct?

If so, does this mean that a write() system call will return quickly only if the target page currently resides in RAM, and must block for the page to be read from disk first otherwise?

Comment: No. It uses the buffer cache if the page isn't in the page cache yet.